# How to disable energy saving on notebook screen when using Scientific Linux 6.3?

Tags: gnome, power-management, laptop, scientific-linux

So there is a notebook that has Scientific Linux 6.3 installed with GNOME 2.

<strike>If we don't press any button on the keyboard or move the mouse,</strike> the screen of it turns black.

But: if we move the mouse/hit a button when the screen of it went black.. it still stays black.. it's not a hardware problem, it's a problem related to the OS. I didn't find any energy saving options for this in the BIOS.

If the screen is black, we can slightly see that the OS is still running, but it's very-very-very dark..

The only solution is to press the power-on button for 5 seconds to turn the machine off..

Any solutions/settings? Please halp.

UPDATE#1: (I can only rarely get to this notebook, that's why I can only answer rarely, sorry) So I found a settings in gnome-screensaver-preferences: "Activate screensaver when computer is idle" was enabled. I disabled it, and we are waiting for the blank screen to appear again, but this takes time, because I found out that the screen goes to blank randomly (!). Even if there was somebody in front of the notebook and was using the ex.: USB mouse.. strange.. I will update the Q/accept the good answer if this helps:D

UPDATE#2: 
Until the outcome the xset -q output is this:

```
[root@HOSTNAME ~]# xset -q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  30
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                    fadfffefffedffff
                    9fffffffffffffff
                    fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0    WhitePixel:  16777215
Font Path:
  catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
[root@HOSTNAME ~]#
```

Comment: Could you [examine its brightness ACPI settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#ACPI)?  Maybe `echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` does something (then the problem might be cornered)

Comment: that would be just a workaround, but BIG THANKS for it :)

Comment: Did either of the answers provided help you out? Can you please update your status on your question? thanks.

Comment: I tried the: "echo 15 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness" when the screen was blank, but it didn't worked :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the xorg.conf file exists in /etc/X11.. that was the problem.. it was related to the recent problem with rhel/xorg.. that the screen was blank when booted the PC

removed the xorg.conf file, problem solved..

Answer (score 3):

There are some suggestions in this Redhat KB doc.

- https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Power_Management_Guide/index.html#gnome-power-manager

#### 1. Using GNOME Power Managment Applet

Usually I open up the `GNOME Power Management` applet and disable any dimming etc. when on AC power. Have you done these things as well?

**Right click on the `GNOME Power Management` icon in your taskbar:**

[image: ss gpm applet]

**Select Preferences from the menu:**

[image: ss of GPM menu]

**Disable dimming and make everything else Never:**

[image: ss gpm prefs. AC tab]

#### 2. `gconftool-2`, `setterm` & `xset`

If the above doesn't work out you can always throw this script at it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Disable screensaver start
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t bool /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/screensaver/start_screensaver false

# Disable screensaver locking
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/lock_enabled false

# Disable screensaver altogether
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false

# Increase screensaver idle time (max 2h, we set to 10h)
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_delay 600

# Disable DPMS screen blank on AC and battery
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t string /apps/gnome-power-manager/ac_dpms_sleep_method off 

gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t string /apps/gnome-power-manager/battery_dpms_sleep_method off

# Disable Computer sleep when on AC and battery
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t integer /apps/gnome-power-manager/ac_sleep_computer 0 

gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t integer /apps/gnome-power-manager/battery_sleep_computer 0

# Disable Display sleep when on AC and battery
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t integer /apps/gnome-power-manager/ac_sleep_display 0 

gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t integer /apps/gnome-power-manager/battery_sleep_display 0

# Disable Dim-on-Idle
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s -t bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/dim_on_idle false

# Setterm
setterm -powersave off -blank 0

# xset stuff
xset -dpms
xset dpms 0 0 0
xset s noblank
xset s off
```

Scripts courtousey this [ubuntuforum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11303989).

Comment: It's in System -> Preferences -> Power Management too.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `$xset -q` or `xset -q | grep timeout` and `xset -q | grep Standby` and see if the output is something like this respectively:

```
timeout:  0    cycle:  600
Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
```

Gnome should let you set the values for `Standby`, `Suspend` and `Off` to `0` through their power saving settings related to the display. The first part, `timeout`, is related to the screensaver, but you should be able to set it to 0 with this command:

```
xset s off
```

The last part, `cycle`, hasn't been a problem, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in this trouble, until I found this a very simple solution: install caffeine and enjoy.

https://launchpad.net/caffeine

It works in every system that I have ever tested.